# Print a JFrame onto a full page

Tags: java, swing, printing

I'm trying to make a Java class in which a JFrame that contains JLabels will be printed on a full A5 page (The JFrame is set to be the size of an A5 page)

in order to do so I've used this class

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/examples/PrintUIWindow.java

with this class that I've written

```
public class test2 extends PrintUIWindow {

    public test2(JFrame f) {
        super(f);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        JFrame f=new JFrame ("hello");
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setSize(420,595);
        JLabel test=new JLabel ("issuer");
        f.add(test);
        test.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(310, 50), test.getPreferredSize())); 
        f.setBackground(Color.white);
        f.setVisible(true); 
        PrintUIWindow p=new PrintUIWindow (f);
        p.actionPerformed(null);
    }
}
```

the problem is that instead of printing the whole JFrame onto the page, it prints just a part of it and the rest is off the borders of the page

what could fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/gui.html)

I also found this:

```
public static class Printer implements Printable {
  final Component comp;

  public Printer(Component comp) {
    this.comp = comp;
  }

  @
  Override
  public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int page_index)
  throws PrinterException {
    if (page_index > 0) {
      return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    // get the bounds of the component
    Dimension dim = comp.getSize();
    double cHeight = dim.getHeight();
    double cWidth = dim.getWidth();

    // get the bounds of the printable area
    double pHeight = format.getImageableHeight();
    double pWidth = format.getImageableWidth();

    double pXStart = format.getImageableX();
    double pYStart = format.getImageableY();

    double xRatio = pWidth / cWidth;
    double yRatio = pHeight / cHeight;


    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.translate(pXStart, pYStart);
    g2.scale(xRatio, yRatio);
    comp.paint(g2);

    return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
  }
}
```

To Print the frame using Printer class try this:

```
JFrame yourComponent = new JFrame();
PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PageFormat preformat = pjob.defaultPage();
preformat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
PageFormat postformat = pjob.pageDialog(preformat);
if (preformat != postformat) {
  pjob.setPrintable(new Printer(yourComponent), postformat);
  if (pjob.printDialog()) {
    pjob.print();
  }
}
```

Comment: It works partially, the frame still needs to be pulled upwards.
How do I change that?

Comment: by partial you mean what part? it should print the whole frame.

Comment: As I first tried the class you gave me the jframe appeared fully on the page but it was smaller than the page and it appeared exactly in the middle of the page. I tried to enlarge the size of the jframe but then when I printed it, instead of expending from the middle of the page to all the borders equally, it didn't expend to the top of the page, so the button of the JFrame was left out of the page

Comment: Have you tried scaling it to desired size via g2.scale(xRatio, yRatio); ??

Comment: I did but no matter how much I changed these settings it wont print on the top of the page

Comment: Add a java.awt.print.Paper, set it to your needs, then PageFormat.setPaper(paper).